# VS 2012 Intellisense suggests treeChild instead of true

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

My intellisense almost always goes for "treeChild" when I start typing tr, instead of "true". It's a really small thing, but it's kinda annoying since I will sometimes accidentally press return and it puts treeChild into my bool.

Any ideas why this is or how to get rid of it?

I never even used treeChild. Or looked at it.

Comment: What's your project type? I tried it on my side with different project types and it looks like here is no option 'treeChild'. If this issue persists for all project types, you can have a try with run the command: devenv /resetuserdata, /safemode, /resetsettings to troubleshot the VS factors, or go to Control Panel-Programs and Features and right click the VS 2012 to repair. Since the latest update of VS 2012 is VS 2015 update 5: https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=48708, if you have not installed yet, try to install it to have a test.

Comment: treeChild is one of our own classes, no idea what we use it for (it's legacy code). Shouldn't Intellisense priorize by what I use most, or what I probably use most (by Intellisenses guess)?

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2012, IntelliSense can pre-select the members that you have recently selected in the pop-up List Members box for automatic object name completion, during your current session in the IDE. You can check this: [IntelliSense for Most Recently Used Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aaw2184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

To turn off this default behavior, go to *Tools-Options-Text Editor-C#-IntelliSense* and uncheck the option “**Pre-select most recently used member**” as below, then click ‘OK’ to save this modification.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to my questionn, as I never actually used "treeChild", so it's certainly not my most recently used member.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstand, does the above option is checked or not in your VS 2012? Please go to Tools-Import and Export Settings, click ‘Reset all settings’ and save your current setting, then reset to the default setting, after that, restart the VS to test this issue again.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't change anything, still getting treeChild as first suggestion :/